# Error in rep(no, length.out = len) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure' comes up during the CellChat tutorial

Tags: r

I am attempting to run the CellChat tutorial online with one data set from the data_HumanSkin. I have been successful running the tutorial up until the Preposing the Expression Data for Cell-Cell Communication. I have been getting the same error at the same spot and have not been able to move forward with the analysis.

```
#set the ligand-receptor interaction database
CellChatDB <- CellChatDB.human
showDatabaseCategory(CellChatDB)

dplyr::glimpse(CellChatDB$interaction)

CellChatDB.use <- subsetDB(CellChatDB, search = "Secreted Signaling")
cellchat@DB <- CellChatDB.use
```

Everything is fine up until this point

```
#preposing the expression data for cell-cell communication analysis 
cellchat <- subsetData(cellchat)

if (future::supportsMulticore()) future::plan(future::multiprocess)
if (future::supportsMulticore() == FALSE) future::plan(future::multisession)

future::plan("multisession")
cellchat <- identifyOverExpressedGenes(cellchat)
cellchat <- identifyOverExpressedInteractions(cellchat)
```

#This is where I get the error after running the identifyOverExpressedGenes.

[image: Screenshot from tutorial where I am stuck]

Comment: (1) The deprecation notice is clear, don't use `future::multiprocess`, use `future::multisession` instead. (2) The warning about using this within RStudio is also rather clear. Did you read [`?parallely::supportsMulticore`](https://parallelly.futureverse.org/reference/supportsMulticore.html)? That doc references https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2597#issuecomment-482187011. Either way, those are both _warnings_, not errors. Have you checked the value of `cellchat` after those expressions?

Comment: Bottom line, do _either_ `options(parallelly.supportsMulticore.unstable=TRUE)` _or_ `Sys.setenv(R_PARALLELLY_SUPPORTSMULTICORE_UNSTABLE="quiet")` before you load `future` and set the `plan`, and the second warning should be silenced. (If not, report the bug.)